# Graph ignores #NA for zero

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a bar graph where cells are formatted with =if(j9 = "", NA(),j9), yet the graph shows #N/A for the data label.  This graph is part of a series of graphs, where in the other graphs this formula is used successfully.

I've right clicked on the graph to Select Data and then Hidden and Empty Cells.  I've right clicked on the data cell to Clear Contents and Delete.  I've changed the formula by replacing NA() with "" and back again.

The graph was displaying blanks correctly until I made an adjustment to the data label for a bar that was not displaying one.  Once the data label showed up in the bar representing new data, the #N/A appeared.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is a question for [superuser](https://superuser.com) :)

Comment: Found the solution after I asked the question, based on a different question I read in this forum.  I checked the chart format and saw that it was for double bars when this chart was a single bar chart.  The problem went away when I changed the format of the chart.